# How to add a custom popup on django admin page in the change view section?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

```
def comments(self, obj):
    return format_html('<a class="button" href="{}?_popup=1">Add Comment</a>',
                       reverse('admin:create-leadcomment', args=[obj.pk]))
```

I want this link to open in a new popup window.

Comment: Well everything that is changed at the client, should be handled with HTML/CSS/JavaScript. Not Django. You should thus write some JavaScript file to do that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use target="_blank" is your  tag as the following:

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Visit W3Schools!</a>
```